# Assigning an event handler that runs on another thread

Tags: windows-phone-8, autoresetevent

I'm trying to fit the windows phone 8 image capture code into a legacy model where I essentially have

```
var _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
```

...

```
_autoResetEvent.Reset();
CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);
cameraCaptureTask.Show();

_autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

...

```
void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e) {
        SaveImage(e);
}
```

Is there a way to get the event handler to run the completed event on another thread so that the AutoResetEvent won't be blocking it from running when it is called?

Comment: Not directly. A UI component is going to raise events on the UI thread. Why would you want to?

Comment: Unless I refactor a large portion of the calling code to give me some kind of "continuation" I need to have it call this and other functions synchronously and wait for each to finish.

Comment: To clarify: script thread ->(conxtex switch)->cameracapture() wait()->(context switch)->script thread->imageprocess() wait()->(context switch)->script thread etc...

Comment: But you're blocking the UI thread by putting a `WaitOne` ....

Comment: Right, so is there a way to have cameraCaptureTask.Completed execute code in another thread that will call _autoResetEvent.Set(); So execution doesn't enter the blocked thread?

Comment: You can't stop execution of the UI thread without causing the UI to freeze. That's definitely not what you want to do. You need to disable the UI other ways.